# Mongo best practice to structure nested document array

Tags: mongodb

I've been struggling to find a solution to the following problem and seem to get conflicting advice from various mongodb posts.  I am trying to figure out how to correctly represent an "array" of sub-objects such that:

1. they can be upserted (i.e. updated or new element created if needed, in a single operation)
2. the ids of the objects are available as values that can be searched, not just keys (that you can't really search in mongo).

I have a structure that I can represent as an array (repr A):

```
{
    _id: 1,
    subdocs: [
        { sd_id: 1, title: t1 },
        { sd_id: 2, title: t2 },
        ...
    ]
}
```

or as a nested document (repr B)

```
{
    _id: 1,
    subdocs: {
        1: { title: t1 },
        2: { title: t2 },
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to update OR insert (i.e. upsert) new subdocs without having to use extra in-application logic.

In repr B this is straight-forward as I can simply use set

```
$set: {subdocs.3.title: t3}
```

in an update with `upsert: true`.

In repr A it is possible to *update* an *existing* record using an 'arrayFilter' with something like:

```
update({_id: 1}, {$set: {subdocs.$[i].title: t3}}, {arrayFilter: [{i.sd_id: 3}], upsert: true})
```

The problem is that while the above will update an existing subobject it will not create a new subobject (i.e. with _id: 3) if it does not exist (it is not an upsert).  The docs claim that $[] does support upsert but this does not work for me.

While repr B does allow for update/upserts there is no way to search on the ids of the subdocuments because they are now keys rather than values.

The only solution to the above is to use a denormalized representation with e.g. the id being stored as both a key and a value:

```
subdocs: {
    1: { sd_id: 1, title: t1 },
    2: { sd_id: 2, title: t2 },
    ...
}
```

But this seems precarious (because the values might get out of sync).

So my question is whether there is a way around this?  Am I perhaps missing a way to do an upsert in case A?

UPDATE: I found a workaround that lets me effectively use repr A even though I'm not sure its optimal.  It involves using two writes rather than one:

```
update({_id: 1, "subdocs.sd_id": {$ne: 3}}, {$push: {subdocs: {sd_id: 3}}})
update({_id: 1}, {$set: {subdocs.$[i].title: t3}}, {arrayFilter: [{i.sd_id: 3}]})
```

The first line in the above ensures that we only ever insert one subdoc with sd_id 3 (and only has an effect if the id does not exist) while the second line updates the record (which should now definitely exist).  I can probably put these in an ordered bulkwrite to make it all work.